# Is there a way to embed audio (MP3) on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, embedded, media-streaming

I would like to embed a (MP3) audio file on a SharePoint online page.

The file is uploaded in a library but somehow embedding audio does not work.

Does anyone have a solution and/or a workaround for this?

Comment: How do you want to embed it? play the audio on loading of the page or provide widgets on the page to play the audio?

Comment: Hi @harshalgite I would like to use a webpart as installing widgets is not possible in the company I am working for. I can only use the standards of SharePoint Online.

Comment: On which page are you trying to embed it? modern or classic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **Embed** webpart in SharePoint Online.

Use your code in **Website address or embed code** like below:

```
<iframe height="200" width="300" src="siteUrl/DocumentLibrary/file.mp3"></iframe>
```

**official documentation**:

[Add content to your page using the Embed web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8).

Comment: You can change the height and width as per your requirements.

Comment: Try using this solution and let me know if this works for you or if you come across any issues using this.

Comment: Great @ganeshsanap! Thanks. Do you have any suggestions about getting rid of the "black screen" and just show the "play-visual"

Comment: I am afraid but this is standard [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) code in HTML which does not support styling directly in html code. However you can change the height and width.

Comment: In order to create a link and play audio/video on click of link, you need to build the custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) solution (if you are familiar with development) and use the code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619074/play-iframe-video-on-click-a-link-javascript).

Comment: Please [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this helped you in any way.